# 'kotlin' is an interesting java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long error

Tags: android, kotlin

In the same application, I am using the following functions to handle user input. The first one works without issues, but the second one throws an exception. What am I missing?

This is the logcat output:

```
Process: com.example.barkod okuyucu, PID: 9955
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "9786257901444"
at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:361)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:352)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318)
```

MainActivity2.kt (this works without errors):

```kotlin
var barkod = intent.getStringExtra("m1")
binding.textView2.text = barkod.toString()
val context = this
var db = DataBaseHelper(context)
binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
    var etadi = binding.editTextText.text
    var etsnkullanmatrh = binding.editTextNumber.text
    var etadet = binding.editTextNumber2.text
    var etbarkod = binding.textView2.text
    if (etadi.isNotEmpty() && etsnkullanmatrh.isNotEmpty()) {
        var kullanici = Kullanici(etadi, etbarkod.toLong(), etsnkullanmatrh.toInt(), etadet.toInt())
        db.insertData(kullanici)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "lutfen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

MainActivity3.kt (this throws the error):

```kotlin
var barkod = intent.getStringExtra("n1")
binding.textView3.text = barkod
val context = this
var db = DataBaseHelper(context)
binding.button3.setOnClickListener {
    var etadi = binding.editTextText2.text
    var etsnkullanmatrh = binding.textView5.text
    var etadet = binding.editTextNumber4.text
    var etbarkod = binding.textView3.text
    if (etadi.isNotEmpty() && etsnkullanmatrh.isNotEmpty()) {
        var kullanici = Kullanici(etadi, etbarkod.toLong(), etsnkullanmatrh.toInt(), etadet.toInt())
        db.insertData(kullanici)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "lutfen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: When posting your code, please format it properly, following indentation guidelines from the [Android Style Guide](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide), so that people can understand your code and your question better. Otherwise, they will have difficulty answering you. Also, when posting two code samples that look almost identical, explain what the essential differences are. In this case, the string on which you call `toLong()` is invalid. Check the exact content of the string, particularly in case it contains whitespace.

Comment: i understand, I'll take it into consideration. besides, the codes are already the same. I'm asking why he makes mistakes on the other when he's already working on one.

Comment: From the log, it looks like there's a newline after the number. The `toLong()` function doesn't accept newlines, only digits. But I'm not sure why one piece of code works and the other doesn't.

Comment: A couple of things: Please use proper code formatting (Just hit Ctrl+L in Android Studio, and it does it for you). This helps you in many cases as it visualizes control flow properly. Also, please use `val` instead of `var` if possible as it prevents accidental modifications to your data if you don't intend to modify your data.

Comment: Lastly, to your question: I tried to reproduce it with the input string you provided, but I cannot reproduce the exception. Therefore, please _edit_ your question and include details about what you were doing in the app to cause the exception (were you hitting enter on the keyboard?) Alternatively, set a breakpoint at the line that causes the exception and have a look at the string in the debugger. Does it contain any invisible characters?

Comment: @vatbub in the original log it looked like there was a newline after the numeric string, which is probably what caused the error. Unfortunately, you edited the question and removed that newline.

Comment: @k314159 Feel free to look at the edit history. I was careful not to edit the logcat output, only the Kotlin code and description around it. I even copy-pasted the string mentioned in the logcat output before editing the question to ensure that there was no weird character in it, but was still unable to reproduce the exception.

Comment: @k314159 According to the edit history, the newline was edited out by Sezar himself.

Comment: @k314159 And that also explains why I couldn't reproduce it anymore...

Comment: @k314159 i got it done. thank you for your interest.

Comment: @vatbub i got it done. thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've edited it out of your code snippet, but it seems you had a newline in the string you were trying to convert to a Long. If you want to read numbers from a multiline input, you can avoid this error by trimming your text before you convert.

```
var kullanici = Kullanici(
    etadi, 
    etbarkod.trim().toLong(), 
    etsnkullanmatrh.trim().toInt(), 
    etadet.trim().toInt())
```

Comment: I handled it in a very similar way to yours. thank you for your interest.